# Pass data from one window to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

Hello everyone I have the following code to take the location I need to use those values to send them to another page or component if someone could help me it would be very useful greetings

```
      const processManualLocation = () => {
        const  url = `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=.........`;
        const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("POST", url);
        http.onreadystatechange = function(){
          if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
           let resultado = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
           let latitude = resultado.location.lat;
           let longitude = resultado.location.lng;
           console.log(latitude, longitude);
          }
        }
        http.send();
    }
```

Comment: You should invalidate that API key that you posted in your question and then generate a new one to use (and keep it secret).

Comment: The title says passing data Passing data from one window to another in React, but your question is really talking about sending an HTTP request with parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to use the [Google Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview).

Here's an example of a asynchronous function for fetching data from that endpoint:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAECUFMDMC5QBYBckAcDOsQBNIDdIAbAe1UgCd0A6Ac2OJsMioGNiBbYdgQw2G2IsAru0gA7JNyQBLYmOA1IxEiymz5xAuTzTIAdwCwAKGNsx6JKACCABQCSAfQDSAUQCaoALygABm+JC5KDcLEhC3ITW9qAA1pAAnj4A3MbG3OjxYiyg0EJZMnKgqOSCkOjoALLcYuGEADKCaoUAFACUoADexqCgZhY9gZHePshomCB6k7T0jJC80tRsnIrKjQXyeACMCkoqUpAA-HHxngAkHbaOrm4AvsndvXL95JAAjkJllt5i+hBvHxZmoMADSdURIBDEbDwADkNgA8gBlAAqMJurRSRh6fUsL3QqCekC8wT03GklmgkCQLAQzRe70+GIe0mgoGaAEI8QTzMxiDF2hCSnpQD9hS5yCVyM0YVB8YSRcRLPCnDCmVjHuZLNgpNxidxSeTQFzCVQAFboORtTHYp6WDohYTkELxUF7dbwDqEKSusQ0G43YnayTWjXPMpCQhfToOwLO13e0CEX03EN9ZTMEg0OnhyNqnovMLkMRGnNIJKgECgYhBPQIfZaUCkiSgJDEEuF4vQErsFsIInGnmgIPcYw3IA)

```ts
// Ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview

const API_KEY = `Your actual API key`;

async function processManualLocation () {
  const  url = `https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=${API_KEY}`;
  const request = new Request(url, {method: 'POST'});
  const response = await fetch(request);
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Response not OK');
  const data = await response.json();
  const {accuracy, location: {lat, lng}} = data;
  const result = {accuracy, lat, lng};
  console.log(result);
  return result; // or whatever want to return from the response data
}
```